# Unable to scan components from sub-package - Spring Jar

Tags: eclipse, spring, executable-jar

I'm developing a spring command line app which uses dependency of external jars. When I run the app from eclipse it works perfectly, but when I export it as runnable jar it fails to autowire the dependecies from the sub-package. However if I write each bean definition in spring-context, then it works. What is the problem with it? Is `@Component` not working or `component-scan base package` or something else?

Here is Spring-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:/connection.properties, classpath*:/log4j.properties" />
    <import resource="classpath*:/sm-service-context.xml" />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.hca.sm.migration" />

    <bean class="com.hca.sm.migration.MigrationController" />

</beans>
```

Update: ERROR Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.hca.sm.migration.MigrationController#0': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.hca.sm.migration.soap.util.SOAPMessageUtil com.hca.sm.migration.MigrationController.soapMessageUtil; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.hca.sm.migration.soap.util.SOAPMessageUtil] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.hca.sm.migration.SMMigrationApp.main(SMMigrationApp.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.hca.sm.migration.soap.util.SOAPMessageUtil com.hca.sm.migration.MigrationController.soapMessageUtil; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.hca.sm.migration.soap.util.SOAPMessageUtil] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.hca.sm.migration.soap.util.SOAPMessageUtil] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 20 more
ERROR [main] (SMMigrationApp.java:17) - org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.hca.sm.migration.MigrationController#0': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.hca.sm.migration.soap.util.SOAPMessageUtil com.hca.sm.migration.MigrationController.soapMessageUtil; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.hca.sm.migration.soap.util.SOAPMessageUtil] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

MigrationController.java:

```
package com.hca.sm.migration;

import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
/* other imports */

@Component
public class MigrationController extends AbstractEntityUtil {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MigrationController.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    protected SOAPMessageUtil soapMessageUtil;

    @Autowired
    protected SOAPGroupUtil soapGroupUtil;

    @Autowired
    protected SOAPMessageThreadUtil soapMessageThreadUtil;

    @Autowired
    protected RestServiceUtil restServiceUtil;

    private SecureMail connectionPort = null;
    private GroupList groupList = null;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        connectionPort = soapConnectionUtil.getSOAPConnection();
    }

    public void migrateOldSmToNew(String clientId, String dryRun) {
        groupList = soapGroupUtil.getListOfGroupsByClientId(clientId, connectionPort) ;

        /* other logic*/

    }
}
```

And my main class from where I call the controller:

```
package com.hca.sm.migration;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public final class SMMigrationApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String clientId = "dc=ihcs,dc=com";
        String dryRun = "true";

        try {
            ApplicationContext smApplicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/SM-MigrationApplicationContext.xml");
            // migration
            MigrationController migrationController = (MigrationController) smApplicationContext.getBean(MigrationController.class.getName());  //here is error
            migrationController.migrateOldSmToNew(clientId, dryRun);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the error stacktrace?

Comment: you could try to inspect the command line of the process launched by Eclipse to run your application, and look for the difference with the command you use to run your runnable jar.

Comment: Could you post your MigrationController?

Comment: Make sure your classpath in jar contains sm-service-context.xml file, or compare the classpath from eclipse with the one from jar.

Comment: @DominikKunicki I have added it. The problem is it does not autowire classes from sub-package e.g. com.hca.sm.migration.util,  com.hca.sm.migration.util.helper etc.

Comment: I could not find a constant naming convention for your xml-configs. First you have listed Spring-context.xml in wich you import sm-service-context.xml. Then in your Config you load SM-MigrationApplicationContext.xml. Maybe here is something wrong or you have a little mistake in naming or your demonstration here . I suggest to give the MigrationController Bean a name in your xml-config and load Bean only by Class: smApplicationContext.getBean(MigrationController.class)

Comment: @s.kwiotek that's not an issue. The issue is it can load dependency from the same package, but fails to load it from sub-package by itself. However if I explicitly define them in `<bean class="...." />`  it works.

Comment: Thats how Spring solves creating Beans. You have to define that Bean in your Context before you can Autowire respectively create it with smApplicationContext.getBean(...).

Comment: @s.kwiotek I am using `@Component` annotation which doesn't require beans to be declared in xml config file.

Comment: Thanks @ns12. I mean either xml or annotation config before you can use getBean(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKAY! So after much of digging I chose another approach to pack my application as runnable jar and it seams to work for me. However I still don't get why the `component-scan-base package` was is not working in this case. I assume it has to do something with the way maven assemble the jar and `.classpath` inside `menifest.mf`. So I suggest if anyone is having such problem use following plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
           <goals>
               <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
     </executions>
 </plugin>
```

This is the most simple way to create standalone runnable jar which includes all the dependencies.

To compile and package run maven command at console:

```
mvn clean package
```

To run the jar at console :

```
java -jar jarName.jar
```

Hope this helps someone like me!!!!